# Saving added items in a combobox to a file

Tags: c#

I am having issues writing to a file in a C# program for class.

My program loads a .txt file to a combo box, which has 3 state options. Users can add up to 5 additional states from a selected list. On Exit, the program saves the added information back to the .txt file if the user chooses Yes.

My issue is that the code below is adding the default states back into the list. Should I be using an If statement under the foreach statement, or is there a way to write it so that only the User-added states are added to my .txt file and not all values all over again?

```
private void saveMyFile()
{
    try
    {
        StreamWriter outputFile;
        outputFile = File.AppendText("states.txt");
        foreach (var cbitem in statesComboBox.Items)
        {
            outputFile.WriteLine(cbitem);
        }
        outputFile.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Your information has been saved. Closing program.");
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data could not be written to file");
    }
}
```

Comment: No one can help you better than yourself by simply removing the exception-eating `catch` clause and see the actual error message.

Comment: I think you just need to save what the user adds into a list or something by handling the related event on selection, then loop through this list and save it if the user decides to save.

Comment: when initially populating your combobox, save the list that you put in - you are reading it from a file anyway. when storing it, only add the new ones to the file by comparing with the list you loaded initially.

Comment: Is there any exception you can post?

Comment: It’s not throwing an exception. The output file looks like:
OR
WA
CAOR
WA
CA
UT
HI
It’s repeating the original 3, and I’m trying to figure out how to just have the new user-added items added to the file. Would this be an If statement outside of the foreach, or is there a way to word this in the foreach criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things you can do to achieve this.

- If the order of the items in the combobox is fixed, you can skip the first x items when saving:

  ```
  private int ExistingStates = 3; // You can later change this number when
                                  // loading the items.
  private void saveMyFile()
  {
      StreamWriter outputFile;
      outputFile = File.AppendText("states.txt");
      foreach (var cbItem in statesComboBox.Items.Cast<string>().Skip(ExistingStates))
      {
          outputFile.WriteLine(cbItem);
      }
      outputFile.Close();
  }
  ```
- You can have an array of the existing items so you can check if the item being saved already exists:

  ```
  private string[] ExistingStates = {"state1", "state2"}; // Add items to the array
                                                          // after loading them.
  private void saveMyFile()
  {
      StreamWriter outputFile;
      outputFile = File.AppendText("states.txt");
      foreach (var cbItem in statesComboBox.Items)
      {
          if (!ExistingStates.Contains(cbItem))
              outputFile.WriteLine(cbItem);
      }
      outputFile.Close();
  }
  ```
- Another option is to overwrite the existing items by replacing the [`AppendText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext) method with [`CreateText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext(v=vs.110).aspx):

  ```
  private void saveMyFile()
  {
      StreamWriter outputFile;
      outputFile = File.CreateText("states.txt");
      foreach (var cbItem in statesComboBox.Items)
      {
          outputFile.WriteLine(cbItem);
      }
      outputFile.Close();
  }
  ```

  Or you can replace the whole method with one simple line (using the [`WriteAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines(v=vs.110).aspx) method):

  ```
  File.WriteAllLines("states.txt", statesComboBox.Items.Cast<string>());
  ```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. I went with the first option since they are fixed, and we haven't really touched on arrays enough. I thought about re-writing the entire file as well, but adding after the first 3 static values is what I wanted. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Note that with this option, you'd need to update the value of `ExistingStates` each time you load the items. ***They wouldn't always be 3***.